# Nginx ingress host 404 ip found

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am beginner with Kubernetes. I tried to deploy Prometheus from helm and now I need to setup Ingress in internal network.

I have problem with resolving Prometheus by hostname. If I use IP address I get it work but when I use syntax "host" it is 404 error. I don't know why is not resolved by hostname. I used kubespray for deploy Kubernetes.

Could you help me, please?

Ingress

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - prom.tipsport.it
    secretName: foo-tls
  rules:
  - host: prom.cluster.local
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090


Describe pod
Name:             prometheus-ingress
Namespace:        monitoring
Address:          10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4,10.10.10.5
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  foo-tls terminates prom.tipsport.it
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus:9090 (10.233.66.116:9090)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: true
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    7m36s (x8 over 61m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    7m35s (x8 over 61m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    7m34s (x8 over 61m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
  rules:
  - host: prom.tipsport.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```

The `host:` field tells it which Host header to route where so it should be the public hostname. Also it should be in the same section as the `http:` field which gives further routing instructions. also you don't need the rewrite target annotation since no rewriting is needed.